# MS Access Requery Recordset moves back to Top of Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

thanks in advance for your support.

I have a ms Access Form that displays data as a spreadsheet. I added the Me.Recordset.Requery instrction to the form as follows.

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
Me.Recordset.Requery
End Sub
```

The requery runs, however after running, the focus takes me back to the top of the form. As far as I understand, the me.recordset.requery instruction should not move the view back up, right?

Any suggestion to correct this?

Thanks

Comment: Well, I just did a test of this method and focus did not move to first record.

Answer (score 0):

My table is very long. I detected this happens after scrolling about 250 lines down. When I did the first test with a few records it seemed to work.

Regards.